# Will redirecting a site from a .com domain to a .ie domain affect SEO?

Tags: seo, redirects, top-level-domains

I have 2 domains. My old domain (on Bluehost) is now redirecting to a new domain (on Blacknight).

Home page is successfully redirecting, but other internal links are still pointing to old domain. I'm looking to change them so they all point to the new one.

1. Will this affect SEO for the website?
2. Does it make any difference to crawlers if the old domain is `.com`
   and new one is `.ie`?

The website is primarily oriented toward Irish visitors.

Comment: Is your site meant only for visitors from Ireland?

Comment: "other internal links are still pointing to old domain." - until you change your internal links then this will be bad for users as well as SEO.

Answer (score 1):

There is the UX element to this in that the user journey is inconsistent.

But it can also be bad for SEO if the site has a lot of external links. Rankings will be affected if a lot of the external links are pointing to the homepage URL (they usually do)  but the rest of the site is on another URL scheme.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to 301 redirect all of the pages from the previous domain to the new one as 301 redirects retaim 90-100% link juice.

Having your site on a .ie domain is fine, but there are a lot of people who believe that .com domains may score better with ranking for global traffic than using a country tld.

Google once did rank .com websites higher than other domaim extensions and there's no telling if that is still raking place.

If you are trying to rank your .ie website for people of that country, there's a good chance that you will get more traffic from that country but less from around the world.